# Checking for disk failures and issues in a VM

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, xen

If you host with a provider who runs a RAID 10 or another RAID based system and your in a VM. Are you able to check for disk failures or RAID failures from within the VM or does it require host based access.

I've noticed some disk issues and my hosts says there is nothing wrong but the side effects of data corruption says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to see hardware details from your VM instance.

This is a discussion you should have with your provider.

- If stability is an issue, complain or leave.
- Look at your contract. If the SLA isn't being met, complain or leave.

These businesses thrive on the bet that people don't want to own/maintain hardware. But at hosting-scale, you're likely on low-end equipment anyway, so this is a conversation you have to have with your provider.